# What should I test to make sure PowerShell remoting is working?

Tags: powershell, winrm, pester

I've read bits and pieces about what to check if you have trouble getting remoting to work in PowerShell on Windows in a domain.

But I've never found a comprehensive guide.

Is there anything more to check besides what's in the Pester test below?

```
Describe '- Windows PoSH Remoting Tests' {
    It 'Should be running WinRM Service' {
        $Status = (Get-Service -Name 'WinRM').Status
        $Status | should -Be 'Running'
    }
    It 'Should test ok for WSMan' {
        Test-WSMan | Should -BeTrue
    }
    It 'Should allow WinRM in FW' {
        $WinRMFireWallRule = Get-NetFirewallRule | where Name -eq 'WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP'
        $WinRMFireWallRule.Enabled | Should -BeTrue
        $WinRMFireWallRule.Action | Should -Be 'Allow'
        $WinRMFireWallRule.Profile -contains 'Public' | Should -Not -BeTrue
    }
    It 'Should have computer domain joined' {
        $PartOfDomain = (Get-CimInstance win32_computersystem).PartOfDomain 
        $PartOfDomain | Should -BeTrue
    }
    It 'Should have a PSSession Config available' {
        $PSVersion = [version]::new($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major,$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor)
        $PSSessionConfigs = Get-PSSessionConfiguration | where PSVersion -eq $PSVersion
        $PSSessionConfigs | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty
    }
    It 'Should not have any public interfaces' {
        $NetWorkCategories = (Get-NetConnectionProfile).NetworkCategory
        $NetWorkCategories -contains 'Public' | Should -Not -BeTrue
    }
}
```

When checking the firewall rules I also found `WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP-NoScope` in one instance.
Is that rule created if you enable remoting skiping the network profile check?

```
Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck
```

Comment: I don't know how your tests compare to it, but the official troubleshooting guide is [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Troubleshooting).

Comment: Great. There were some more settings that needs to be checked :)